# MySQL: Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s). What's wrong with my use of WHERE...NOT IN(SELECT...)?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

*Credit:Leetcode_1355. Activity Participants*

Question:
Write an SQL query to find the names of all the activities with neither maximum, nor minimum number of participants.

Return the result table in any order. Each activity in table Activities is performed by any person in the table Friends.

```
Friends table:
+------+--------------+---------------+
| id   | name         | activity      |
+------+--------------+---------------+
| 1    | Jonathan D.  | Eating        |
| 2    | Jade W.      | Singing       |
| 3    | Victor J.    | Singing       |
| 4    | Elvis Q.     | Eating        |
| 5    | Daniel A.    | Eating        |
| 6    | Bob B.       | Horse Riding  |
+------+--------------+---------------+

Activities table:
+------+--------------+
| id   | name         |
+------+--------------+
| 1    | Eating       |
| 2    | Singing      |
| 3    | Horse Riding |
+------+--------------+

Result table:
+--------------+
| activity     |
+--------------+
| Singing      |
+--------------+
```

My code is as follows:

```
WITH a AS(
    SELECT activity, COUNT(1) AS n 
    FROM Friends
    GROUP BY activity
    )

SELECT activity
FROM a
WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT MAX(n),MIN(n) FROM a)
```

I have seen the success of using n != (select min(n) from a) and n != (select max(n) from a), but I did not know why my code went wrong. My guess is that it's because '`SELECT MAX(n), MIN(n) FROM a`' will generate two columns, rather than two rows. While I still don't know the exact reason.

Hope someone can help me out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  But `NOT IN` does work that way -- because the subquery returns multiple columns.  And you are comparing to only one value.  Instead, use two separate comparisons:

```
SELECT activity
FROM a
WHERE n <> (SELECT MAX(n) FROM a) AND
      n <> (SELECT MIN(n) FROM a) ;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that it's because `SELECT MAX(n), MIN(n) FROM a` will generate two columns, rather than two rows.

Yes, that's the point. Other than using two subqueries (which you already found out by yourself), you can also take advantage of window functions here (the fact that you use a `with` clause indicates that you are running MySQL 8.0, which supports window functions):

```
select activity
from (
    select 
        activity, 
        row_number() over(order by count(*) asc)  rn_asc,
        row_number() over(order by count(*) desc) rn_desc
    from friends
    group by activity
) t
where 1 not in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

I suspect that this performs better than a `with` clause and two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the subquery in `WHERE`, you can join with the subquery.

```
WITH a AS(
    SELECT activity, COUNT(1) AS n 
    FROM Friends
    GROUP BY activity
    )

SELECT activity
FROM a AS a1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(n) AS maxn, MIN(n) AS minn) AS a2
ON a1.n NOT IN (a2.maxn, a2.minn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` and `MAX()` window functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT activity, 
         COUNT(*) AS n,
         MIN(COUNT(*)) OVER () min_n,
         MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER () max_n          
  FROM Friends
  GROUP BY activity
)
SELECT activity, n
FROM cte
WHERE n NOT IN (min_n, max_n)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oM7hA5osvGjpjmuoTSZzXj/0).
Results:

```
| activity | n   |
| -------- | --- |
| Singing  | 2   |
```